# sjPlot glmer - how to plot standard error instead of CI bands?

Tags: standards, confidence-interval, sjplot

I've run **glmer** and can happily plot predicted values for fixed effects interactions.

I'd like to see the error band representing std error instead of confidence interval. Is there a way to do this?

So far, I've run:
`model1 <- glmer (choseG ~ group * zBFA + (zBFA | subject), family=binomial(link='logit'), data=data)`

`sjp.int(model1, type = "eff", swap.pred = TRUE, show.ci = T, jitter.ci = T)`

Comment: No, you can't plot std errors, only CI-bands.